# Quiero saber como se suman los múltiplos de cierto número

Tags: java, bucle-for

Tengo que resolver una tarea y tengo duda sobre mi código, ya que no se como sumarlos, seria de mucha ayuda, gracias.

**Tarea**:

Un programa que reciba un número natural ente el rango 1 <= n <= 5*10^5 y determine sus número divisores menores a él y los sume para obtener un nuevo número natural.

Ejemplo: el número 20 tiene 5 divisores  1, 2, 4, 5, 10,20  y la suma de los divisores es: 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10+20= 42.

Imprimir los divisores y la suma total de los mismo.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        
        System.out.println("Ingresa un número:");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        
        for(int i = 1 ; i <=n ; i++){
            if(n%i==0){
             System.out.println("Los numeros divisores son: "+i);                
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    int suma = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Ingresa un número:");
    n = sc.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1 ; i <=n ; i++){
        if(n%i==0){
         System.out.println("Los numeros divisores son: "+i);                
         suma = suma + i;
        }     
    System.out.println("La suma es: "+suma);
  
    }
```

Has usado un contador para recorrer el número introducido por teclado. En el bucle donde lo recorres para encontrar sus múltiplos puedes (dentro del if) poner un acumulador cuando los vaya encontrando que vaya sumándolos. Fuera del if pones otro system.out.println con el resultado.

Comment: Además del código, podías explicar un poco tu solución. Añadiría valor tanto a la pregunta como a la respuesta, mejorando el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

**Los divisores de un un número n se hallan debajo de la raíz cuadrada del número**, esto es un teorema matemático de la teoría de números, ej los divisores de **100**, solamente tenemos que iterar desde **1** hasta la raiz cuadrada de **100** y de esta forma obtenemos todos sus divisores, tener esto en cuenta hará a tu algoritmo mas eficiente, lo q se traduce en un tiempo de ejecución más rápido, por tanto :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n;
int division;
int suma = 0;
int raiz= Math.sqrt(n);

System.out.println("Ingresa un número:");
n = sc.nextInt();

for(int i = 1; i <= raiz; i++)
{
   if(n % i == 0)
   {
      division = n/i;
      suma = suma + i + division;
   }
}

System.out.println("La suma es: " + suma);
```

Hacemos un **ciclo for** desde **1** hasta la raiz cuadrada del número y vamos preguntando si el número es divisible por **i**, a través del **operador %**, el cual devuelve el resto de la división, un número es divisible por otro cuando el resto de la división (**n % i**) es **0**,
en caso de que el número sea divisible, pués hallamos la división(**/**) de **n** con **i**, y posteriormente sumamos el valor de la **variable suma** + la posicion actual del **ciclo for** (**i**) + la división del número, por último imprimimos la **variable suma**.

Comment: Muchas gracias.