# Números abundantes

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio en el que introduzcan un valor, si el valor es un texto diga que "No es un numero" y si es un numero o varios compruebe si es de tipo abundante. De momento voy así pero no me funciona...¿Alguna ayuda?

```
function ejercicio2(){
    var param;
    var preguntar;
    var array=new Array();
    
    do{
        param=prompt("Introduce un parametro: si no es un numero sale.");
        array.push(param);
    }while(!isNaN(param));
    alert("Hay "+abundantes(array)+" numeros abundantes.");
}

function abundantes(array){
    var suma;
    var contador=0;;
    
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        suma=1;
        for(var j=2; j<array[i]; j++)
            if(array[i]%j==0)
                suma+=j;
        if(suma>array[i])
            contador++;
    }
    
    return contador;
}
```

Comment: Qué significa "no  me funciona"? QUé error obtienes? Cuál es el resultado incorrecto? Por favor, edita la pregunta y explícalo también

Comment: No me funciona porque el resultado no es el que tiene que ser. No da ningún error. Simplemente el resultado no es el correcto.

Answer (score 2):

Un [número abundante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_abundante#:%7E:text=En%20matem%C3%A1ticas%2C%20un%20n%C3%BAmero%20abundante,%CF%83(x)%20%3E%202x.&text=Unos%20pocos%20de%20los%20primeros,ejemplo%2C%20consideremos%20el%20n%C3%BAmero%2024.) es un número entero en que la suma de sus divisores es mayor que él. Para calcular los divisores del número entero basta con recorrer los divisores desde el 1 hasta la mitad del número.
Definimos la función abundante(n) que nos retornará un booleano indicando si es abundante o no, posteriormente aplicamos la función a los elementos del array que has construido.

**Primeros números abundantes**

12, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 42, 48, 54, 56, 60, 66, 70, 72, 78, 80, 84, 88, 90, 96, 100, 102,...

```js
function abundante(n){
  let divisores = 0;
  let es = false;
  for (let div=1;div<=n/2;div++) {
    if (n % div == 0){
      divisores = divisores + div;
    }
  }
  if (divisores > n) {
    es = true;
  }
  return es;
}

let arr = [1,2,3,6,12,24,30,36,945];
for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  if (abundante(arr[i])){
    console.log(arr[i], 'es abundante');
  }
}
```

Comment: Para optimizar tu algoritmo, los divisores de un numero se hallan dividiendo desde 1 hasta la raiz cuadrada del numero

Comment: El 8 es divisor de 16, y la raiz cuadrada de 16 es 4. Con esta condición no llegamos al 8.

Comment: Si llegamos, la raiz de 16 es 4, y por debajo de este numero tenemos el 2 que es un divisor y al dividir entre este numero 2 es como obtenemos el 8, esto es un teorema matematico y se usa para optimizar la busqueda de numeros primos, se llama division por tentativa, investigalo

Comment: Así lo haré. Gracias por la info.

Comment: Vincent revisando un poco encontre esta respuesta de hace ya un tiempo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411808/quiero-saber-como-se-suman-los-m%c3%baltiplos-de-cierto-n%c3%bamero/411933#411933